# Can I use personal Office 365 small business premium install on my job work computer

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, licensing

I have an office 365 small business premium subscription that entitles me to 5 installs. I use it for my small business, consisting of me only. I do have a couple of installs left.

I am also a full-time employee of a big company. Is it legal to use one of these installs on a laptop provided by my employer?

Comment: What does your licence agreement say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is within your license of o365. The only restriction is the number of devices.

However you should check with the IT department of the company who's laptop it is as to whether they permit such use.

Comment: I checked with Microsoft too. They say that it is OK as long as I am using it.